# Access 2010 or SQL Server 2008 Export Query to Custom Text File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, export-to-csv

I am looking for a way to output records to a custom text file.  The key is the text file has two parts: 1. Command Script 2. Data Records  The purpose is to output the file to a Watch folder where a Label Software will open the file process the Command Script and print the data records on labels.  I am using an Access 2010 Front-end and SQL Server 2008 backend. The text file is formated with the Script commands on lines 1 & 2 and the data begins on line 3.  Below is an example of the text file:

%BTW% /AF="C:\ShippingLabelName.btw" /D="%Trigger File Name%" /PRN="LabelPrinterName" /R=3 /P /DD
%END%
"PackSlipNo","ShipLotNo","Qty","CustRev","CustPartNo","ShipDate","CustPO","Descrip","PartNo","SupplierNum","ID","MyQty","MyPartsPer","Dock","City","UserDefined1","UserDefined2","UserDefined3","UserDefined4","SerialNum"
"99007865",20120097,24402,"NONE","440510404",6/18/2012 0:00:00,"0203109703","PINTLE","33949","9090551",9420,5,1000,"JRZ 2","SANTA TERESA",,,,,"150535"

Comment: Is this a one time shot?  In Management Studio, select the database, right-click and select Tasks->Export Data OR select Management, right-click and select Export Data. either of these will lead you to a wizard that will walk you through exporting to different kinds of formats including flat file options.  Pop the Command Script on top manually.

You can also run your query from the Query window and save the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the files separately using VBA ([DoCmd.TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768%28v=office.11%29.aspx), [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)) and use the DOS Copy command, also within VBA, to concatenate the two files ( http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Combine_Two_Files_(Concatenate) )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't a one-time shot, the way I handle this kind of requirement is with the age-old open and print commands used to create precisely-customized text output files.  Here's a little sample code.  This sample was pipe-delimited, but this method will allow you to output anything you want.

```
Open vpath For Output Lock Write As #1
Print #1, vmemo & "|" & Trim(rs!Memo) & "|" & Format(rs!txndate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "|" & rs!RefNumber & "|" & "Paid" & "|" & Format(rs!AppliedToTxnAmount, "#,##0.00")
```